# Cannot print screenshot to sdcard on emulator (eclipse)

Tags: android, eclipse, storage, emulation, screenshot

I continually get an error.
Each time that I run the code in the emulator, it shows the 'Toast' that the directory was created, but there must be an error shortly after that line of code.  The error that comes up is:

"/storage/sdcard/Pictures/screenshot.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)"

I have place the relevant code below.

```
<manifest
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" 
    />
    <uses-permission  
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" 
        android:maxSdkVersion="18" 
    /> 
</manifest>

public class myActivity {

private void openScreenPrint() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)){
        View v1 = findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout).getRootView();
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap myBM = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
        saveBitmap(myBM);
        v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Permission to Write", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    String filePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
    File dir = new File(filePath);
    if (!dir.exists()){
        dir.mkdirs();
        Toast.makeText(this, "created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //This line shown every time
    }
    String fileName = "screenshot" + ".png";
    File imagePath = new File(filePath, fileName);  
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        //Log.e("Err", e.getMessage(), e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Log.e("Err", e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you created an SD Card in your AVD? If not, here's the entry that you'll want to use when creating/editing your simulated device:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I had added 100 MiB in this location you have shown.  It didn't seem to change the error.

Comment: Which API is your AVD running?

Comment: Target: Android 4.4.2-API Level 19

Comment: Google's changed how external storage works; they've severely limited the locations that can be used. You can check out this post by CommonsWare (http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) for some background. BTW, your code ran fine on both real and virtual API 16 devices, but failed on an API 19 AVD.

Comment: The second post in that series might be more apropos: http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html

Comment: I only need to store the image somewhere accessible that will work for multiple devices.  What is the suggested store location?

Comment: You should be able to use String filePath = getExternalFilesDir(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getAbsolutePath();

Comment: Note that the physical location, which you shouldn't really care about if you use the recommended methods, will be a bit different. The new location is /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/<package>/files/Pictures .

Answer (score 0):

You do not actually know that the directory is actually being created. You are making the Toast whether the directory create succeeds or not. You should change this section:

```
if (!dir.exists()){
    dir.mkdirs();
    Toast.makeText(this, "created", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

to test if the directory was actually created successfully. File.mkdirs() returns a boolean.

```
if (!dir.exists()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "dir not exists. attempting to create...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (dir.mkdirs()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "dir created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "dir creation failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: the outside check is for `dir.exists()` so it's covered here. but good thing to point out for others.